# Why ModelState is not valid even though Employee ID is the primary key

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Why model state is not valid even though Employee ID is the primary key? Even if I am not using `[Required]` data annotation on `Employee ID`.

In my case, using the database-first approach, and ASP.NET Core 7.0, and Create and Edit the same action. But Edit case is 100% working fine. But when we created a new employee, that error occurs.

Screenshot of model is available here:

[image]

Comment: You should not be using EF entity classes as two-way view-models in ASP.NET - doing so causes problems like this because a view-model will need different property members (and attributes/annotations) compared to an EF entity - but also because of over-posting attacks. Don't do it.

Comment: Something else is definitely wrong here. An `int` property will never make the ModelState invalid. Could you post the error message of the ModelState?

Comment: In asp.net core 6+, even if you are not using `[Required] `data annotation on property, it will  show null warning. But the int default is 0, it won't be invalid. Could you share the full code of the Employee model ? And the try to  set a breakpoint at ModelState.IsValid to see the result .